# ECDSA host key for has changed - add host with all ports to ignored

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, docker

I'm using Docker, so I have single host with multiple IPs. From time to time I have to rebuild images, so when I try to SSH to this host I'm getting warning:

```
ECDSA host key for [192.168.0.196]:285 has changed and you have requested strict checking
```

Of course I can use `ssh-keygen` command to remove it but this won't be the best solution for my case.

So the question is - is there any option to permanently add 192.168.0.196 (together with all ports) to ignored to not verify them? As I said I will be using multiple ports - sometimes it will be 285, sometimes 286 and so on, so preferred way would be adding only host (together with all ports) to ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems in `.ssh/config` has to be added:

```
Host 192.168.0.196
   StrictHostKeyChecking no
   UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
```